# Distribution for average of multiple binomial proportions

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, proportion, central-limit-theorem, estimators

Assume we have a population $N$ and a proportion $p$ of that population with a characteristic of interest. Both $N$ and $p$ are unknown. Furthermore, assume that we have $k$ random samples $(n_i, x_i)$ of $N$ from which we can estimate the proportion of interest $\hat{p}_i = x_i/n_i$ for each sample, with $i=1,\ldots,k$.

Additionally, $n_i$ and $x_i$ are large enough so that the CLT kicks in and we can say that, with $\mathbb{E}[\hat{p}_i]=p$ and $\mathbb{V}[\hat{p}_i]=\frac{p(1-p)}{n_i}$, then $\hat{p}_i\sim\mathcal{N}\left(p,\frac{p(1-p)}{n_i}\right)$.

I am interested in the behavior (especially towards the right tail) of $\bar{p}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \hat{p}_i$. So far, the approach I have thought of is the following: since each $\hat{p}_i$ is normally distributed, then their average $\bar{p}$ also follows a normal distribution since the arithmetic average is just a weighted sum where the weight is constant. More specifically, $$\bar{p}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \hat{p}_i \sim\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kp,\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{p(1-p)}{n_i}\right) \equiv \mathcal{N}\left(p,\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{p(1-p)}{n_i}\right)$$

My questions are:

1. Is my line of reasoning correct regarding the distributions, both of individual $\hat{p}_i$ and the resulting $\bar{p}$?
2. Since we do not know the true value $p$, is it reasonable to substitute it with corresponding $\hat{p}_i$ in the calculations? For the last step, this would result to
   $$ \bar{p} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k\hat{p}_i, \frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\hat{p}_i (1-\hat{p}_i)}{n_i} \right) \equiv \mathcal{N}\left(\bar{p}, \frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\hat{p}_i (1-\hat{p}_i)}{n_i} \right) $$

This approach seemed reasonable to me because we "know" (under some assumptions) the distribution of each component $\hat{p}_i$, and therefore of $\bar{p}$ itself, but if someone has a different proposal on quantifying the (right) tail behavior of $\bar{p}$, please feel free to share it.

---

**EDIT**: some background and clarifications

This is an important topic for banks when modeling credit risk. In this context, we have a sample of obligors, size $n_i$, of which $x_i$ have defaulted, and $i$ here represents one year. So if we have $k$ years of data $\{(x_i,n_i)\}_{i=1}^k$, we can calculate the observed (or estimated) probabilities of default experienced each year, $\hat{p}_i = x_i/n_i$, $i=1,\ldots,k$.

We consider the $n_i$ to be a random sample each time it is chosen. If the standard constraints about the relationship between $n_i$ and $p_i$ are fulfilled (i.e. $p_i$ is not too close to either $0$ or $1$, $n_i$ is above some threshold for CLT to apply, etc.), then we can approximate the distribution of each $p_i$ through the normal approximation as mentioned above. From a regulatory point of view, the behavior of $\bar{p} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k \hat{p}_i$ is of particular interest.

Comment: So you have several simple random samples (of different sizes) from the same population. Are these different samples done in an independent way? Do you have information about the individuals in each sample (so you can account for individuals sampled repeatedly?), or only the proprtions? The individual $\hat{p}_i$s will not be independent, but we could find out the (approximate) joint distribution. Please clarify these details.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I added some details which hopefully address your points. The samples can be assumed to be independent so it's allowed to view $\hat{p}_i$'s as independent. Generally, this should be considered as the most "benign" case (i.e. making all the assumptions that significantly facilitate calculations and reduce model complexity).

Comment: **This estimator is inadmissible.** A better estimator (one with lower variance) is $$\tilde{p} = \frac{ n_1\hat{p}_1+n_2\hat{p}_2+\cdots+n_k\hat{p}_k}{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k} = \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k}{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k} .$$ The second expression reveals this to be a multiple of a random draw from a Binomial$(n_1+\cdots+n_k, p)$ distribution, allowing you to apply the usual estimates. Is there some regulatory restriction that requires you to use this (inadmissible) estimator?

Comment: @whuber There is indeed some [regulation](https://eba.europa.eu/sites/default/documents/files/documents/10180/2192133/f5a2e068-dc4b-4a0e-a10f-378b517ac19c/Guidelines%20on%20PD%20and%20LGD%20estimation%20(EBA-GL-2017-16)_EN.pdf), stating in p. 23: "[...]  institutions should calculate the observed average default rates as the arithmetic average of all one year default rates". This could be because each $\hat{p}_i$ is subject to its own portfolio composition and economic conditions (which change from year to year), so no two $\hat{p}_i$'s will be from the same generating mechanism.

Comment: I understand that this comes in direct contradiction with the initial statement about the samples coming from the same population of unknown size $Ν$ and probability $p$, which I will edit out promptly. But I do not suspect this to have any effect on the rest of my rationale because we treat each $(x_i, n_i)$ as independent from each other anyway.

Comment: Thank you: the regulatory involvement is interesting.  (I am fascinated by regulations that impose mathematically or statistically unreasonable restrictions on calculations--there are plenty in the US.)  But if the $n_i$ don't vary much, the difference wouldn't be worth worrying about.

Comment: Have you find the solution of your problem. I'm also concerned about it (EBA Guideline). Also, from a PD backtest point of view, how do can you adapte it to long term average definition of default rate.